# how to add a value "1" for each values in a file, using python or bash

Tags: python, bash

how to add a value "1" for each number in a file, using python

I have a file that looks like this;

```
C1-S0
C2-S0
C3-C1
C1-S0-C2
S0-C1-H7
S0-C1-C3
C2-C4-C3
C2-C5-H10
O6-C5-H10
C2-C5-O6
C3-C1-S0-C2
H7-C1-S0-C2
C4-C2-S0-C1
C5-C2-S0-C1
```

using python or bash, how to add a value of 1 for each number that exists in this file. for atentre the following results:

```
C2-S1
C3-S1
C4-C2
C2-S1-C3
S1-C2-H8
S1-C2-C4 
C3-C5-C4
C3-C6-H11 
O7-C6-H11
C3-C6-O7
C4-C2-S1-C3
H8-C2-S1-C3
C5-C3-S1-C2
C6-C3-S1-C2
```

Comment: what about `C6-C3-S1-C9` ? does it become `C6-C3-S1-C10` ?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: read file line by line, extract last char/int, add 1 convert back to char/slice/write back to another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't ask for perl, but I'm going to show it anyway:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)/$1+1/ge' file
```

If you want to write back to the original file, use `perl -i -pe ...`

Comment: thanks, thanks, and thanks .... can I put all the values in parentheses ()
For example
S1 to S (1)

Comment: @Hamzaallal yes, you can

Comment: okay, with bash ??

Comment: Should me ask another question or it already exists in the stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Hamzaallal You should try and solve the problem yourself first... 

If that fails then you do some research to try and figure out how to solve the problem...

This website isn't a programming service, you shouldn't just ask a question "do x for me". There's a reason why your question here has been downvoted a bunch of times.

And the solution can be done in pretty much any language.

Comment: thank you very much, thank you for any information, I am not a developer nor a computer scientist ... I tried to do some scripts to facilitate my task in my work chemistry.
..... i will try ..... thanks for your time.

Comment: @Hamzaallal all you need to do is slightly modify glenn's answer. What his answer does is find any number in the file `(\d+)` and replace it with that number + 1 `$1+1`. So what you want to do, is instead of replacing it with `$1+1`, replace it with `$1+1` surrounded by brackets.

Comment: dear explv thank you very much, I understood